# Installing git-svn generates errors for dependancies

Tags: linux, git, svn, yum, rhel

I am trying to install git-svn package on different redhat releases it always generates errors because of packages dependencies, I tried to solve those dependencies and nothing solved, I created a repo config with a url, but it didn't solve the problem.

Create the repository config file /etc/yum.repos.d/puias-computational.repo:

```
[puias-computational]
name=PUIAS Computational
baseurl=http://puias.math.ias.edu/data/puias/computational/6.4/i386/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

yum install git-svn

This out on RH6.4, I tried on 6.3 and 6.5 and same happens

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git-svn.noarch 0:1.7.11.4-3.puias6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: git = 1.7.11.4-3.puias6 for package: git-svn-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: git-svn-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git::SVN::Ra) for package: git-svn-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git::SVN::Prompt) for package: git-svn-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git::SVN::Fetcher) for package: git-svn-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git::SVN::Editor) for package: git-svn-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.i686 0:1.7.11.4-3.puias6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.11.4-3.puias6 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.1 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.4 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
---> Package perl-Git-SVN.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-1.sdl6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: git = 1.8.3.1-1.sdl6 for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
---> Package perl-TermReadKey.x86_64 0:2.30-13.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package expat.i686 0:2.0.1-11.el6_2 will be installed
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.1-2.el6_0.1 will be updated
---> Package git.i686 0:1.8.3.1-1.sdl6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.8.3.1-1.sdl6 for package: git-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.i686
---> Package libcurl.i686 0:7.19.7-35.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssh2(x86-32) >= 1.4.2 for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so(NSS_3.4) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so(NSS_3.2) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so(NSS_3.11.4) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssh2.so.1 for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libsmime3.so for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libplds4.so for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libplc4.so for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnssutil3.so for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.9.3) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.9.2) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.5) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.4) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.3) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.2) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12.5) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12.1) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.10) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnspr4.so for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libldap-2.4.so.2 for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkrb5.so.3 for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libk5crypto.so.3 for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libidn.so.11(LIBIDN_1.0) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libidn.so.11 for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgssapi_krb5.so.2(gssapi_krb5_2_MIT) for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgssapi_krb5.so.2 for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcom_err.so.2 for package: libcurl-7.19.7-35.el6.i686
---> Package openssl.i686 0:1.0.0-27.el6 will be installed
---> Package pcre.i686 0:7.8-6.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) for package: pcre-7.8-6.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: pcre-7.8-6.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: pcre-7.8-6.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: pcre-7.8-6.el6.i686
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.7.1-2.el6_0.1 will be updated
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.7.11.4-3.puias6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.11.4-3.puias6 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
---> Package perl-Git-SVN.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-1.sdl6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
---> Package zlib.i686 0:1.2.3-29.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package krb5-libs.i686 0:1.10.3-10.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux.so.1 for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-10.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1(KEYUTILS_0.3) for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-10.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1 for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-10.el6.i686
---> Package libcom_err.i686 0:1.41.12-14.el6 will be installed
---> Package libidn.i686 0:1.18-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package libssh2.i686 0:1.4.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libstdc++.i686 0:4.4.7-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package nspr.i686 0:4.9.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package nss.i686 0:3.14.0.0-12.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nss-softokn(x86-32) >= 3.12.9 for package: nss-3.14.0.0-12.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libsoftokn3.so for package: nss-3.14.0.0-12.el6.i686
---> Package nss-util.i686 0:3.14.0.0-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package openldap.i686 0:2.4.23-31.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.2 for package: openldap-2.4.23-31.el6.i686
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.7.1-2.el6_0.1 will be updated
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.7.11.4-3.puias6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.11.4-3.puias6 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-1.sdl6 will be an update
---> Package perl-Git-SVN.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-1.sdl6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cyrus-sasl-lib.i686 0:2.1.23-13.el6_3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so for package: cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.el6_3.1.i686
---> Package keyutils-libs.i686 0:1.4-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package libselinux.i686 0:2.0.94-5.3.el6 will be installed
---> Package nss-softokn.i686 0:3.12.9-11.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsqlite3.so.0 for package: nss-softokn-3.12.9-11.el6.i686
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.7.11.4-3.puias6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.11.4-3.puias6 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
---> Package perl-Git-SVN.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-1.sdl6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package db4.i686 0:4.7.25-17.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.7.11.4-3.puias6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.11.4-3.puias6 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
---> Package perl-Git-SVN.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-1.sdl6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
---> Package sqlite.i686 0:3.6.20-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.6 for package: sqlite-3.6.20-1.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.7.11.4-3.puias6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.11.4-3.puias6 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
---> Package perl-Git-SVN.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-1.sdl6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
---> Package readline.i686 0:6.0-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtinfo.so.5 for package: readline-6.0-4.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ncurses-libs.i686 0:5.7-3.20090208.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.7.11.4-3.puias6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.11.4-3.puias6 for package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686
---> Package perl-Git-SVN.noarch 0:1.8.3.1-1.sdl6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) for package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch (puias-computational)
           Requires: perl(SVN::Client)
Error: Package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch (puias-computational)
           Requires: perl(YAML::Any)
Error: Package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch (puias-computational)
           Requires: perl(SVN::Core)
Error: Package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch (puias-computational)
           Requires: perl(SVN::Delta)
Error: Package: git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.i686 (puias-computational)
           Requires: perl-Git = 1.7.11.4-3.puias6
           Removing: perl-Git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.noarch (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201301301459.x86_64/6.4)
               perl-Git = 1.7.1-2.el6_0.1
           Updated By: perl-Git-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch (puias-computational)
               perl-Git = 1.8.3.1-1.sdl6
           Available: perl-Git-1.7.11.4-3.puias6.noarch (puias-computational)
               perl-Git = 1.7.11.4-3.puias6
Error: Package: perl-Git-SVN-1.8.3.1-1.sdl6.noarch (puias-computational)
           Requires: perl(SVN::Ra)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2):

Guys Thanks for who were trying to help me.

After long searching I could find this URL repo could help to solve this problem it's a CentOS but it works on RedHat:

put the bellow inside >> /etc/yum.repos.d/centos-6-x86_64-rpms.repo
[centos-6-x86_64-rpms]

name = CENTOS 6 x86_64 (RPMs)

baseurl = http://mirror.bitco.co.za/centos/6/os/x86_64

enabled = 1

gpgcheck = 0

gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

then try:

yum install git-svn